# How to exclude nodes from path?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I want to get all mathematicians from DBpedia, so I wrote this query for [DBpedia's SPARQL service](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person
{
  ?person dct:subject ?category.
  ?category skos:broader* dbc:Mathematicians.
}
```

The problem with this is that the category `Mathematicians` is polluted, due to categories like [dbc:Euclid](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Euclid), which then includes all of Euclidean geometry. I believe it's categories like these which cause the query to fail:

> Virtuoso 42000 Error TN...: Exceeded 1000000000 bytes in transitive temp memory.  use t_distinct, t_max or more T_MAX_memory options to limit the search or increase the pool

A lot of the problematic categories are in [dbc:Wikipedia_categories_named_after_mathematicians](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Wikipedia_categories_named_after_mathematicians).

Is there some way to ignore these categories in the `skos:broader*` path that would make the error go away?

Comment: I guess a problem here is that the DBpedia category hierarchy which is based on the Wikipedia categories can contain cycles, i.e. that might be a reason for the error - although this should not happen, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the categories that you don't want to include by filtering them out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person
{
  ?person dct:subject ?category.
  ?category skos:broader* dbc:Mathematicians.
  FILTER (?category NOT IN (dbc:Euclid))
}
```

But that won't remove the error because Virtuoso still needs to traverse the `skos:broader` hierarchy, exhausting 'transitive heap memory'. Other approaches include selecting specific categories or traversing part of the hierarchy.

The specific category could use `UNION` statements, but the `VALUES` shortcut is a simpler syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person
{
  VALUES ?category {dbc:Mathematicians dbc:Mental_calculators dbc:Lists_of_mathematicians}
  ?person dct:subject ?category.
}
```

For querying part of the hierarchy, you can use some property path expressions.  This one will get parents and grandparents:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person
{
  ?person dct:subject ?category.
  ?category skos:broader | (skos:broader/skos:broader) dbc:Mathematicians.
  # filter as desired - FILTER (?category NOT IN (dbc:Euclid)) 
}
```